# Adding a decimal fraction to a number using onclick() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, decimal, parsefloat

I am building a calculator, and I am attempting to add a decimal to a number in JavaScript using an onclick method. So I have one function called `handleNumberClick` that will return any integer I click, and then have another function that should in theory add a decimal to the value of the number function.

I used the `parseFloat` method, thinking that would be the answer to my problem, but it doesn't seem so. My decimal function is `handleDecimalClick`.

#### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="calculator">
        <div id="top-row">
            <button id="clear" onclick="clearMemory()" value="">
                C
            </button>
            <input id="display" type="number" maxlength="6">
            </input>
        </div>
        <div id="second-row">
            <button id="seven" onclick="handleNumberClick(7)" value="7" class="number">
                7
            </button>
            <button id="eight" onclick="handleNumberClick(8)" value="8" class="number">
                8
            </button>
            <button id="nine" onclick="handleNumberClick(9)" value="9" class="number">
                9
            </button>
            <button id="plus" onclick="handleOperationClick('add')" value="+" class="op">
                +
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="third-row">
            <button id="four" onclick="handleNumberClick(4)" value="4" class="number">
                4
            </button>
            <button id="five" onclick="handleNumberClick(5)" value="5" class="number">
                5
            </button>
            <button id="six" onclick="handleNumberClick(6)" value="6" class="number">
                6
            </button>
            <button id="minus" onclick="handleOperationClick('subtract')" value="-" class="op">
                -
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="fourth-row">
            <button id="one" onclick="handleNumberClick(1)" value="1" class="number">
                1
            </button>
            <button id="two" onclick="handleNumberClick(2)" value="2" class="number">
                2
            </button>
            <button id="three" onclick="handleNumberClick(3)" value="3" class="number">
                3
            </button>
            <button id="divide" onclick="handleOperationClick('division')" value="/" class="op">
                /
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="fifth-row">
            <button id="zero" onclick="handleNumberClick(0)" value="0" class="number">
                0
            </button>
            <button id="decimal" onclick="handleDecimalClick()" value='.' class="number">
                .
            </button>
            <button id="equals" onclick="handleOperationClick('evaluate')" value="=" class="number">
                =
            </button>
            <button id="multiply" onclick="handleOperationClick('multiplication')" value="x" class="op">
                x
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var operatorPressed = false;
var prevOperand = 0;
var currentOperand = 0;
var operationRequested = '';
var decimalAdded = false;

// Creates calculator display input
var displayNumbers = document.getElementById("display");

// Clears calculator display and var a values
function clearMemory()  {
    displayNumbers.value = '';
    prevOperand = 0;
};

function clearDisplay() {
    displayNumbers.value = "";
};

// Displays values on calculator screen
var displayValue = function(num) {
    if (displayNumbers.value.length > 9) {
        displayNumbers.value = "ERROR";
    }
    else {
        displayNumbers.value = parseFloat(num);
    };
};

function handleNumberClick(num) {
    currentOperand = operatorPressed ? num : displayNumbers.value += num;
    operatorPressed = false;
    displayValue(currentOperand);
    console.log(num);
    parseFloat(num);
    console.log(prevOperand + 'prevOperand');
    console.log(currentOperand + 'currentOperand');
};

function handleDecimalClick() {
    currentOperand.value += '.';
    //console.log(displayNumbers.value);
}

function clearNumberEntered() {
    numberEntered='';
    clearDisplay();
}

// Operators functions
function handleOperationClick(operator) {
    var result;
    operatorPressed = true;
    switch(operationRequested){

        case 'add':
            result = add(prevOperand, currentOperand);
            break;

        case 'subtract':
            result = subtract(prevOperand, currentOperand);
            break;

        case 'multiplication':
            result = multiply(prevOperand, currentOperand);
            break;

        case 'division':
            result = divide(prevOperand, currentOperand);
            break;

        case 'evaluate':
            result = equate();
            break;

        default:
            result= '';
    }

    if (operationRequested) {  // If an acutal computation occurs, we'll
                               // store overwrite the result to the prevOperand
        displayValue(result.toFixed(2));
        prevOperand = result;
        operationRequested = '';
    }
    else { // If no computation occurs we'll just set the input val as the prevOperand
        prevOperand = currentOperand;
        operationRequested = '';
    }

    //console.log("operation:%s %d to %d", operationRequested, currentOperand, prevOperand );
    operationRequested = operator || operationRequested;
    console.log(operationRequested);
}

function add(num, adder) {
    var sum = parseFloat(num) + parseFloat(adder);
    return sum;
}

function subtract(num, subtracter) {
    var difference = parseFloat(num) - parseFloat(subtracter);
    console.log(difference);
    return difference;
}

function multiply(num, multiplier) {
    var product = parseFloat(num) * parseFloat(multiplier);
    return product;
}

function divide(num, divisor)    {
    var quotient = parseFloat(num) / parseFloat(divisor);
    return quotient;
}

function equate()    {
    return prevOperand;
    console.log(displayNumbers.value);
}
```

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but your `handleOperationClick` has unnecessary logic near the end:  `operationRequested = operator || operationRequested`.  You do not need to set `operator = ""` in the prior if statement, and can simply set `operationRequested = operator`, when you get out of the iff statement,

Comment: `handleDecimalClick()` is referencing `currentOperand.value`, but it should just be `currentOperand += '.';`

Comment: @csum Actually, it needs to be `displayNumbers.value += '.'`, provided that decimal has not already been clicked since the last operator or evaluate.  `displayNumbers` is the input element, a *string*, and `currentOperand` and `previousOperand` are supposed to be numeric (i.e. floating point) values.  That is, `currentOperand` is a primitive value, not an object, and thus does not have a `value` property.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of how far out the decimal goes, and then use that to calculate the power of 10 for the next button press.

```
var powerOfTen = -1;
```

When the user clicks the "." button, set `powerOfTen` to the first value, -1.

```
powerOfTen = -1;
```

Then, when a number button is pressed, multiply it by the 10 to the power of `powerOfTen` and add it to the number you already have. Then, subtract one from `powerOfTen`.

```
number += digit * Math.pow(10, powerOfTen);
powerOfTen--;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the value is being lost in a couple places. The lines in `handleNumberClick` and `handleDecimalClick` where you set the value of `currentOperand`:

```
function handleNumberClick(num) {
    if(operatorPressed) {
      currentOperand = num;
    }
    else {
      currentOperand += num;
    }
    operatorPressed = false;
    displayValue(currentOperand);
    console.log(num);
    parseFloat(num);
    console.log(prevOperand + 'prevOperand');
    console.log(currentOperand + 'currentOperand');
}
function handleDecimalClick()   {
    currentOperand += '.';
    //console.log(displayNumbers.value);
}
```

I haven't tested all of the calculator functionality to look for other issues, but these changes appear to allow decimals to be used.

---

(I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1fk7kdd9/2/) that defines some unit tests. Scroll down in the javascript and look for the `tests` array on line 142. May be useful in tracking down some errors.)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be a homework problem, so I'll just give some suggestions to help you solve the problem.

First of all, keep in mind that your operands are *strings* that *represent* numeric values, not the actual numeric values. This can be seen in your `add`, `subtract`, `multiply`, and `divide` functions, which always do a `parseFloat` on the two arguments. However, the value returned by each of these functions is an actual numeric value. So in each case when you call `displayValue`, you are passing in a *number*. That means the `parseFloat` call in `displayValue` is redundant. What you have isn't technically wrong, but does indicate some confusion.

Similarly, the value passed in to `handleNumberClick` is always a number.  There is no need to call `parseFloat` in that function.  You aren't doing anything with the parsed result anyway, so the call effectively does nothing.

The first statement in `handleNumberClick` is the heart of the problem here.  You have:

`currentOperand = operatorPressed ? num : displayNumbers.value += num;`

If `operatorPressed` is true, `currentOperand` is set to a number (because `num` is a number), which is not consistent with your assumption that it is a string. This is very important, because the meaning of `+` (and `+=`) can be numerical addition or string concatenation, depending on the arguments. Then, if `operatorPressed` is false, `currentOperand` is a string. But you are, in fact,  changing both `currentOperand` (because of `=`) *and* `displayNumbers.value` (because of `+=`), which is probably not what you intended.  Normally, you only use `+=` in something like `x += ...`, rather than on the right side of an assignment statement.  You can do it, but it is pretty rare.

See if that gets you unstuck. If not, post a comment or an update and I'll have another look.